# dataframe missing values show up at the end of each row

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a dataset with missing values. The head of the dataset looks like this:

```
1:0.2 2:0.7 3:-1.2 4:0.5
1:0.9 3:0.1 4:0.8
1:-0.1 2:0.1 4:1.0
2:0.6 3:-1.0
```

The number in front of the colon is the index of the feature. As one can see in some rows, some features are missing. So when I import the data using the following code,

```
df = pandas.read_csv('dataset',header=None,sep = '\s+|:',engine='python')
```

I get the dataframe looks like this:

```
    0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
0   1.0     0.2     2.0     0.7     3.0     -1.2    4.0     0.5
1   1.0     0.9     3.0     0.1     4.0     0.8     NaN     NaN
2   1.0     -0.1    2.0     0.1     4.0     1.0     NaN     NaN
3   2.0     0.6     3.0     -1.0    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

I want to replace the NaNs with 0s in the correct place. But if I use `df.fillna(0)`, I will replace the NaN at the end of each row. What I really want is a dataframe looks like this,

```
    0       1       2       3       4       5       6       7
0   1.0     0.2     2.0     0.7     3.0     -1.2    4.0     0.5
1   1.0     0.9     0.0     0.0     3.0     0.1     4.0     0.8
2   1.0     -0.1    2.0     0.1     0.0     0.0     4.0     1.0
3   0.0     0.0     2.0     0.6     3.0     -1.0    0.0     0.0
```

Comment: Do you really want `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. to be data values? From the phrasing of your question, I would think you just wanted them as indices?

Comment: @rahlf23 yes I just want them as indices. I want to use them to help me to indicate the missing features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `csv` module to construct a list of dictionaries, then feed to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor. Finally, use `fillna` to fill null values with `0`.

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
import pandas as pd

x = StringIO("""1:0.2 2:0.7 3:-1.2 4:0.5
1:0.9 3:0.1 4:0.8
1:-0.1 2:0.1 4:1.0
2:0.6 3:-1.0""")

# replace x with open('file.csv', 'r')
with x as fin:
    L = [dict(i.split(':') for i in line) for line in csv.reader(fin, delimiter=' ')]

df = pd.DataFrame(L, dtype=float).fillna(0)

print(df)

     1    2    3    4
0  0.2  0.7 -1.2  0.5
1  0.9  0.0  0.1  0.8
2 -0.1  0.1  0.0  1.0
3  0.0  0.6 -1.0  0.0
```

Comment: My actual dataset has +1 or -1 at the beginning of each row, which indicates the label of this sample. I can't construct a list of dictionaries in this case.

Comment: @NeyoYang, Unfortunately, that's not the question you asked above. You could [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), this time providing a better input sample and desired output *consistent with your input*.